# Calculate Power Series Coefficients

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

Given a polynomial \$p(x)\$ with integral coefficients and a constant term of \$p(0) = \pm 1\$, and a non-negative integer \$N\$, return the \$N\$-th coefficient of the power series (sometimes called "Taylor series") of \$f(x) = \frac{1}{p(x)}\$ developed at \$x_0 = 0\$, i.e., the coefficient of the monomial of degree \$N\$.

The given conditions ensure that the power series exist and that the its coefficients are integers.

#### Details

As always the polynomial can be accepted in any convenient format, e.g. a list of coefficients, for instance \$p(x) = x^3-2x+5\$ could be represented as `[1,0,-2,5]`.

The power series of a function \$f(x)\$ developed at \$0\$ is given by

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n}$$

and the \$N\$-th coefficient (the coefficient of \$x^N\$) is given by

$$\frac{f^{(N)}}{N!}$$

where \$f^{(n)}\$ denotes the \$n\$-th derivative of \$f\$

#### Examples

- The polynomial \$p(x) = 1-x\$ results in the geometric series \$f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + ...\$ so the output should be \$1\$ for all \$N\$.
- \$p(x) = (1-x)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1\$ results in the derivative of the geometric series \$f(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + ...\$, so the output for \$N\$ is \$N+1\$.
- \$p(x) = 1 - x - x^2\$ results in the generating function of the Fibonacci sequence \$f(x) = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 5x^4 + 8x^5 + 13x^6 + ...\$
- \$p(x) = 1 - x^2\$ results in the generating function of \$1,0,1,0,...\$ i.e. \$f(x) = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + ...\$
- \$p(x) = (1 - x)^3 = 1 -3x + 3x^2 - x^3\$ results in the generating function of the triangular numbers \$f(x) = 1 + 3x + 6x^6 + 10x^3 + 15x^4 + 21x^5 + ...\$ that means the \$N\$-th coefficient is the binomial coefficient \$\binom{N+2}{N}\$
- \$p(x) = (x - 3)^2 + (x - 2)^3 = 1 + 6x - 5x^2 + x^3\$ results in \$f(x) = 1 - 6x + 41x^2 - 277x^3 + 1873x4 - 12664x^5 + 85626x^6 - 57849x^7 + \dots\$

Comment: Would it be acceptable to take a polynomial as an infinite list of power-series coefficients like `[1,-1,0,0,0,0,...]`?

Comment: Yes, I think that this is an acceptable format.

Comment: Nice examples chosen!

Comment: I'm glad you appreciate it, thank you=)

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, <strike>24</strike> 23 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Greg Martin*

```
D[1/#2,{x,#}]/#!/.x->0&
```

Pure function with two arguments `#` and `#2`. Assumes the polynomial `#2` satisfies `PolynomialQ[#2,x]`. Of course there's a built-in for this:

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/#2,{x,0,#}]&
```

Comment: Well done beating the built-in! I guess you can save a byte by assuming that `#` is the integer `N` and `#2` is the polynomial.

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, <s>81 79</s> 75 bytes

Unlike the previous two answers this doesn't make use of symbolic calculations. The idea is that you can iteratively calculate the coefficients:

```
function C=f(p,N);s=p(end);for k=1:N;q=conv(p,s);s=[-q(end-k),s];end;C=s(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#PY0xD4IwEIV3fsUtJDSBoYuDTScnF1jcDAOWa9IAd8Vrjf56rIsv3/CG7@XVmTw/U6Yp4fqB23WAmVGAOIEgbpAYJMdYHPCZXApM4MOKUvX2ZOCfKtp7p9uCHg3UPjyYJucC4Hva4oqH2NggzcqUP1isPvdmt47p1cRWlJEy339Ct6hWRlOauVhptDqOLw)

#### Explanation

```
function C=f(p,N);
s=p(end);            % get the first (constant coefficient)
for k=1:N;           
    q=conv(p,s);     % multiply the known coefficients with the polynomial
    s=[-q(end-k),s]; % determine the new coefficient to make the the product get "closer" 
end;
C=s(1)           % output the N-th coefficient
```

Answer (score 4):

## [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), 28 bytes

```
Derivative[1/A1,B1]/B1!
f(0)
```

Input is taken from the spreadsheet cells A1 and B1 of a polynomial and an integer respectively, and each line is entered separately into the input bar. Output is via assignment to the variable `a`.

Here is a gif showing the execution:

[image: Taylor coefficients]

Using builtins is much longer, at 48 bytes:

```
First[Coefficients[TaylorPolynomial[1/A1,0,B1]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```haskell
p%n=(0^n-sum[p!!i*p%(n-i)|i<-[1..n]])/head p
```

A direct computation without algebraic built-ins. Takes input as an infinite list of power series coefficients, like `p = [1,-2,3,0,0,0,0...]` (i.e. `p = [1,-2,3] ++ repeat 0`) for `1-2*x+x^2`. Call it like `p%3`, which gives `-4.0`.

The idea is if **p** is a polynomial and **q=1/p** is it inverse, then we can express the equality **p·q=1** term-by-term. The coefficient of **x<sup>n</sup>** in **p·q** is given by the convolution of the coefficients in **p** and **q**:

**p<sub>0</sub>· q<sub>n</sub> + p<sub>1</sub>· q<sub>n-1</sub> + ... + p<sub>n</sub>· q<sub>0</sub>**

For **p·q=1** to hold, the above must equal zero for all **n>0**. For here, we can express **q<sub>n</sub>** recursively in terms of **q<sub>0</sub>, ..., q<sub>n-1</sub>** and the coefficients of **p**.

**q<sub>n</sub> = - 1/p<sub>0</sub> · (p<sub>1</sub>· q<sub>n-1</sub> + ... + p<sub>n</sub>· q<sub>0</sub>)**

This is exactly what's calculated in the expression `sum[p!!i*p%(n-i)|i<-[1..n]]/head p`, with `head p` the leading coefficient **p<sub>0</sub>**. The initial coefficient **q<sub>0</sub> = 1/p<sub>0</sub>** is handled arithmetically in the same expression using `0^n` as an indicator for `n==0`.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 12 bytes

```
1 :'(1%u)t.'
```

Uses the adverb `t.` which takes a polynomial `p` in the form of a verb on the LHS and a nonnegative integer `k` on the RHS and computes the `k`<sup>th</sup> coefficient of the Taylor series of `p` at `x = 0`. In order to get the power series, the reciprocal of `p` is taken before applying it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYKhgpa5hqFqqWaKnzpWanJGvoKunkKaQqadgaADha@jqaenqaWII6mpZoQsaYhHT1YszxhDU0FUzjjOy0tTWVTNClv7/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Maple, <s>58</s> 26 bytes

This is an unnamed function that accepts a polynomial in `x` and an integer `N`.

EDIT: I just noticed that there is a builtin:

```
(p,N)->coeftayl(1/p,x=0,N)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
0)i:"1GY+@_)_8Mh]1)
```

Translation of [@flawr's great Matlab answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105286/36398).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@gmWmlZOgeqe0Qrxlv4ZsRa6j5/3@0rqEOEBnGcpkBAA)

#### How it works

```
0)      % Implicitly input vector of polynomial coefficients and get last entry
i       % Input N
:"      % For k in [1 2 ... N]
  1G    %   Push vector of polynomial coefficients
  Y+    %   Convolution, full size
  @     %   Push k
  _     %   Negate
  )     %   Index. This produces the end-k coefficient
  _     %   Negate
  8M    %   Push first input of the latest convolution
  h     %   Concatenate horizontally
]       % End
1)      % Get first entry. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```
(a,n)=>a.reduce((s,p,i)=>!i|i>n?s:s-p*f(a,n-i),!n)/a[0]
```

Port of @xnor's Haskell answer. I originally tried an iterative version but it turned out to be 98 bytes, however it will be much faster for large N, as I'm effectively memoising the recursive calls:

```
(a,n)=>[...Array(n+1)].fill(0).map((_,i,r)=>r[i]=r.reduce((s,p,j)=>s-p*(a[i-j]||0),!i)/a[0]).pop()
```

`n+1` terms are required, which are saved in the array `r`. It is initially zeros which allows reducing over the entire array `r` at once, as the zeros will not affect the result. The last calculated coefficient is the final result.

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, <s>31</s> 27 bytes

```
f->n->Pol(Ser(1/f,,n+1))\x^n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), <del>31</del> 25 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to the comment of [@alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)

```
f(e,R):=taylor(1/e,x,0,R)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcm7CoAgFADQ3a@4o8YVey5JPxHNwaUUgqJIB/16sy1azzkobAelZLnBUfSDp7ifN6@UwYBlpqSZKmAyzsNCzjgoFFs3d@0UueWVDAidEBo@@KqYa4T2F9lleKPJkR4)

Comment: A named function is shorter: `f(e,R):=taylor(1/e,x,0,R)`.